# Anchor 2866 engine torque strut mount is missing in my car does that make my car take off slow?

Tags: engine, buick, torque, motor-mounts

Anchor 2866 is missing completely and the passenger mount is completely shattered and now my car is failing to launch properly. It takes a bit to get it going but once it's going it goes. Will replacing the mounts fix my cars take off?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The torque strut at the top of the engine is there to limit engine movement due to torque reaction so it does not hit other components as it provides power.

The lack of takeoff torque & power may be down to being out of tune or a component is faulty.

A good service / tune may sort that issue.